# Why do I get and error when my loop runs the 2nd time? TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The aim of this code is to change the numbers on the board according to given moves.

This is a simplified excerpt from my code and I'd like the principle to stay the same.

It seems like the code runs through the first loop but then gives an error when it runs through it another time: TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy

board = numpy.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])



boardlist0 = [board]*2

boardlist1 = []
ind = 0
move = [[0,0], [7,4]]


for k in move:
    move = move[ind]

    boardlist0[ind][move[0]][move[1]] = 1

    boardlist1.append(boardlist0)
    ind += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ind = 0
move = [[0,0], [7,4]]

for k in move:
    move = move[ind]
    print(move)
```

prints

```
[0, 0]
0
```

On the second iteration, `move` equals 0. So

```
move[0]
```

raises a `TypeError`.

---

I'm not quite sure what the intention of your code is, but you could avoid the TypeError using `k` instead of `move`. (Below I've renamed `move` --> `moves`, and `k` --> `move`):

```
import numpy

board = numpy.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

boardlist0 = [board]*2
moves = [[0,0], [7,4]]

for move, board in zip(moves, boardlist0):
    board[move[0], move[1]] = 1    

for board in boardlist0:
    print(board)
```

---

Note that `boardlist = [board]*2` makes a 2-element list where each element references the *exact same* object -- not a copy of -- `board`. Thus, altering `boardlist0[0]` affects `boardlist0[1]`, and vice versa. If instead you want two independent boards, use

```
boardlist0 = [board.copy() for i in range(2)]
```